# Refactor javascript class to angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the Microsoft SDK for registration.

They suggest using the following line of code in the `<head>` of `index.html` (it works):

```
var ADAL = new AuthenticationContext({
  instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
  tenant: 'common', //COMMON OR YOUR TENANT ID

  clientId: '8605dbab-5f90-445c-b888-f27f3521e71e', //This is your client ID
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200', //This is your redirect URI

  callback: userSignedIn,
  popUp: true
});
```

I want to instead use this in my `app.component.ts` file, but I can't figure out how to declare `new AuthenticationContext` the "typescript" way.

For example `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})

export class AppComponent {
  AuthenticationContext;
  ADAL = new this.AuthenticationContext({
    ...
  })
}
```

Also, I'm imagining Authentication is a class and not an Object. Should I be looking at "interfaces"?

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/adal-angular/index.d.ts

Comment: I need that entire class to use the properties I described?

Comment: They are typing files, if you want strongly typed then yes you would want to use that. It is used for development time only. You would just do npm-install to dev dependencies.

Comment: Is there no way to just refactor just the contents of `new AuthenticationContext` that I posted (in the first snippet), in a typescript supported way?

Comment: You can, just won't be strongly typed. See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ri8nr7) i just created under `app.component.ts`

Comment: Hi @penleychan in this case `this.userSignedIn` from the `callback` property causes an infinite loop. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: Nope I don’t I never used ADAL before, sorry.

Comment: Needed to put the callback in a closure to prevent the infinite loop. For example, `callback: (err, token) => { this.userSignedIn(err, token); }`